# Typescript thinks boolean check is a string

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, conditional-statements, conditional-operator

I'm running into an issue when I'm trying to check if all of the properties in an object are populated and assigning the result to a boolean. This is the code:

```
this.isAddressValid = address.street && address.city && address.state && address.zip && address.country;
```

When I leave it like this, I get an error that states: `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'boolean'`

But it seems to work if I add a simple conditional to the end:

```
this.isAddressValid = address.street && address.city && address.state && address.zip && address.country ? true : false;
```

I'm wondering why this is happening. Shouldn't the statement become a boolean by using the `&&` operator? Why do I need to add the conditional for this to work?

Comment: "*Shouldn't the statement become a boolean by using the && operator?*" No. Moreover, it's trivial to check: `console.log("hello" && "world")` is *not* `true` but `"world"`.

Comment: `&&` returns the right-hand operand if it was truthy, otherwise the left-hand operand. So, `'a' && 'b'` yields `'b'`, but `'' && 'b'` yields `''`. (`||` does the opposite.) Note that none of these are booleans, because at no point you converted something to a boolean. Most of the time this doesn't matter because you use the result with `if` or `while`, both of which care only about truthyness of the result and not actual equality with `true`. You can do `!!(a && b && c)` (or, more descriptively, `Boolean(a && b && c)`) if you want to convert the result (`!` _does_ always return a boolean).